# Openfire plugin is not updated/refreshed after build + reload

Tags: java, plugins, ant, openfire

I am running Openfire 3.9.3 from source code (in Eclipse), and then build a plugin (using Ant in Eclipse) while Openfire is running. I can see that Openfire auto-reload the plugin each time I build the plugin. The proof is from the log and that the plugin description is updated if I change it in `plugin.xml`. However, it seems that the Java classes is not updated. For example, when I change some *logging text* in the code and re-build the plugin (and then Openfire reloads the plugin), the *logging text* printed is still the old one. It will not be updated until I restart (kill and re-run) Openfire.

Can I have the plugin updated/refreshed each time I build it?

**INFO** I setup my project based on [this instruction](https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by simply removing the plugin (actually it is not the `broadcast` plugin like in the illustration) from the build path.

[image: Java Build Path settings]